# python - multiple value search in list and get values or indexes

Tags: python, arrays, list, search

How can i search for multiple values in dictionary to other dictionary ?

```
findvalues = {'1','2'}
listvalues = {'1':{'A'},'2':{'B'},'3':{'C'},'4':{'D'}}
```

I need to search findvalues in listvalues and get their values or indexes

Comment: [`itemgetter(*findvalues)(lst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) if I understood you right.

Comment: Get their values or indexes?

Comment: Did you mean these to be dictionaries or lists? Right now you have two dictionaries, and the  findvalues dictionary is invalid.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer *findvalues* is a valid set

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer the top one is a `set` and not a `dict`

Comment: woops you are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you aware that the variable *list* is actually a dictionary? You should probably review basic Python [data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary is called `list`. But this is a build-in name. Never use those. [Here is a list of build-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Addionally, are you sure you want to have the items in the `dict` in an extra set? If not, you can just define them as strings:

```
myDict = {'1':'A','2':'B','3':'C','4':'D'}
```

I am not completly sure what you want to achieve. Something like this might do what you want:

```
filteredDict = [myDict[key] for key in findvalues if key in myDict ]
```

It creates a `list` of items which are the values stored at the keys in your `findvalues` set. Additionally it filters out keys that are not inside the list. If you want it rather to throw an exception if that happens, just leave out the `if key in myDict`

To also have the suggested solution from @OlvinRoght's comment in an answer, I'll add this here.

The itemgetter is part of the operator lib, which you will need to import.

```
from operator import itemgetter
filteredDict = itemgetter(*findvalues)(myDict)
```

Comment: Typo -  ... what you want to *achieve*?     The List Comp. can be simplified to - ``` [myDict[key] for key in findvalues if key in myDict]```

Comment: Better answer would be @OlvinRoght's.  But it will need ```import operator```.

Comment: @DanielHao thanks. The `itemgetter` is indeed shorter, maybe even faster, but as this is a beginner question I prefere solutions which teach the core concepts of python.

Answer (score 0):

i made some code that does what the question asks but it is very inflexible, it cant work if there is not the item you are looking for and if you want to search for more than two items it wont work. remember that lists start at 0 not 1

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def find_values(a,b):
    loc3=[]
    for i in range (len(mylist)):
        if a==mylist[i]:
            loc1=i
        if b==mylist[i]:
            loc2=i
    loc3.append(loc1)
    loc3.append(loc2)
    return loc3
print(find_values(2,7))
```